# How do I call npm link on a module that has a different entry other than index.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node module that has `"main": "dist/index.js"` in `package.json`.

Calling `node my-package` from the parent folder successfully calls `dist/index.js` as the entry file.

However, if I call `npm link` it seems to do some sort of action with a progress bar (maybe it's installing something for some reason) and then it says:

`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/Man/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/my-package/index.js'`

Why can't npm link recognize the different entry file? It's looking for index.js.

PS My goal here is to make my module usable in the command line from any directory. Not sure if I'm going about it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"main": "./dist/index.js",
```

in `package.json`. That works for me with `npm link`.

Also run `npm list --link=true` and `npm list -g --link=true --depth=0` and `unlink` your module first in case it's already linked. Sometimes it helps to run `npm cache clean` in case your `link` was somehow messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the response...none of these things worked for me. It's still searching for that index.js file for whatever reason.

Comment: `npm link` can definitely handle a different entry point. Write a dummy hello-world module with `main.js` and try to link that. Work from there and see how these two differ.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my package.json file had `"bin": "./index.js"`. This caused the problem and removing it fixed it.